# Number of set elements in column of type SET (population count)

Tags: mysql, sql, hammingweight

I have a table declaration like

```
CREATE TABLE my_foos (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    bars SET('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five') NOT NULL
)
```

And the values

```
1, ('one', 'two')
2, ('two')
3, ('three', 'four', 'five')
```

Now I want to select id and the [population count](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight) (also called Hamming weight) of bars.

In my example

```
SELECT id, POPCOUNT(bars)
FROM my_foos
```

would return

```
1, 2
2, 1
3, 3
```

**What do I have to do to get the population count?**

<sup>Please don't answer how to do this on the client side. I hope the solution will be usable in WHERE, ORDER BY, HAVING, etc. as well.</sup>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`BIT_COUNT(bars)` returns the number of one bits in the SET.

I did not know/expect that you can simply use the SET datatype like an integer.

- [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b3e83/10/0)

Answer (score 2):

I think there are many ways to solve this particular problem but the approach I am using is this,

```
CHAR_LENGTH(bars) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(bars, ',', '')) + 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b3e83/3)

If you want, you manke that as a `Function`

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION POPCOUNT(popList SET('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'))
RETURNS INT 
BEGIN
    RETURN CHAR_LENGTH(popList) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(popList, ',', '')) + 1;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

and you can call it like,

```
SELECT POPCOUNT(bars) FROM my_foos
```